# Элемент не доступен из-за уровня защиты

Tags: c#, winforms

В форме FormAuth у меня вот такой код поля:

```
public void bunifuMaterialTextbox1_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

В свойствах поля: Разработка -> Name, там Name = bunifuMaterialTextbox1.

В форме Form1 я пытаюсь получить введённое значение в то самое текстовое поле:

```
FormAuth.bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text = label1.Text;
```

Везде стоит Modifiers = Public.

Подскажите в чем тогда ошибка ? Ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Везде стоит Modifiers = Public.

компилятор так не думает, и у него есть основания. По-умолчанию контролы в форму добавляются с модификатором `private`, можно поменять, но это не правильно.

Правильно будет добавить в `FormAuth` отдельные публичные свойства для получения значений из дочерних контролов.

```
partial class FormAuth : Form//или что-то подобное, т.к. код определения
                             //данной формы вы не привели в вопросе
{
    ...//тут код, который у вас уже есть

    public string InputText//назовите как нравится
    {
        get { return bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text; }
        set { bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text = value; }
    } 
}
```

ну и использование

```
var fa = new FormAuth();
fa.InputText = label1.Text;
...//остальные настройки формы если необходимо.
```

Никогда не выставляйте наружу вложенные контролы в явном виде. Это дает возможность не только получить доступ к "нужным" данным из полей ввода, например, но и случайно поменять другие свойства контролов, от чего, например, может "поехать" весь дизайн формы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74999/discussion-on-answer-by-rdorn-------).

Answer (score 1):

```
class FormAuthorization : Form
{
  ...
  public string MaterialText
  {
    get { return bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text; }
    set { bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text = value; }
  }
}

FormAuth.MaterialText = label1.Text;
```